# Can i get XML values where XML value is greater than some number?

Tags: php, xml

I am getting xml feeds from an xml soccer feeder and **i want to select all values from xml feed which ID is greater than my last id from database**...

How i can do that?
Is there something like LINQ in .net where i can select some condition?
**I know for phpLinq**, is there some better idea **without any framework**?

Something like this:

```
$fixtures=
    $this->soccer->GetFixturesByDateInterval(
        array("startDateString"=>$start,"endDateString"=>$end))->Match->Id->where(Match->Id > $number);
```

THis is few feeds from var_dump $fixtures without Match->Id->where etc...

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[5]
public 'Match' => 
array (size=11)
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
      public 'Id' => string '348257' (length=6)
      public 'Date' => string '2015-06-19T00:00:00+00:00' (length=25)
      public 'League' => string 'Brasileirao' (length=11)
      public 'Round' => string '8' (length=1)
      public 'HomeTeam' => string 'Figueirense' (length=11)
      public 'HomeTeam_Id' => string '922' (length=3)
      public 'AwayTeam' => string 'Internacional' (length=13)
      public 'AwayTeam_Id' => string '736' (length=3)
      public 'Location' => string 'Orlando Scarpelli' (length=17)
  1 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
      public 'Id' => string '348051' (length=6)
      public 'Date' => string '2015-06-18T17:20:00+00:00' (length=25)
      public 'League' => string 'Superettan' (length=10)
      public 'Round' => string '14' (length=2)
      public 'HomeTeam' => string 'Degerfors' (length=9)
      public 'HomeTeam_Id' => string '1193' (length=4)
      public 'AwayTeam' => string 'Syrianska' (length=9)
      public 'AwayTeam_Id' => string '593' (length=3)
      public 'Location' => string 'Stora Valla' (length=11)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use XPath.
For example, if you want to select all rows which ID attribute is greater than X:

```
$rows = $xml->xpath("//row[@id>x]");
```

Comment: Can i use xpath like this:

$this->soccer->GetFixturesByDateInterval(
        array("startDateString"=>$start,"endDateString"=>$end))->xpath("//Match[@id>x]")